# To sort an array of array of integer

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I did sort  an array of array of integer by converting it into a vector.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
//#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std ;
int kj;
int aRawdata [3] [4] =  {{1,0,37,52},{2,0,49,49}, {3,0,52,64}};
int aSolution[3] [4];
int main()
{

 //copy aRawdata to aSolution
    copy(&aRawdata[0][0], &aRawdata[0][0] + 3*4, &aSolution[0][0]);     

    // insering a random number into the second column of aSolution; the column which would be base of the sort
    for ( kj = 0 ; kj < 3 ; kj++)
    {       
        aSolution [kj] [1] =  rand();
    }   
    // converting aSolution  into vector (my_vector)     
        {// start sort using the vectors
        vector< vector<int> > my_vector ;
        for( const auto& row : aSolution ) my_vector.push_back( vector<int>( begin(row), end(row) ) ) ;
        sort( begin(my_vector), end(my_vector),
                   []( const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b ) { return a[1] < b[1] ; } ) ;    
        // for Copying a “vector of vector” into“ array of array”
        for (size_t row = 0; row < my_vector.size(); ++row) {
            copy(my_vector[row].begin(), my_vector[row].end(), aSolution[row]);
}       // print 
        for( const auto& row : aSolution )
        {
            for( int v : row ) cout << setw(10) << v ;
            cout << '\n' ;
        }

    }
}
```

I have two questions.

1. How can I copy data of the my_vector (which is a sorted vector) into the aSolution again that result in sorted aSolution array?
2. How can I do the sorting of aSolution directly without using vectors? (sorting would be based on the second column of aSolution).
   Regards.

Comment: aSolution is int, is this your real code? This cannot be compiled. Also, make proper indentation, this code is unreadable.

Comment: @ Sorry I replaced the whole code in the main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector's data is aligned in memory (like a big array) so you could just memcpy it back in as long as you make sure it's of the right size.

As for your second question, just implement quicksort yourself - it takes 5 mns. =) Else, I don't think you can use std's sort without a proper container.